# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS not recognizing external hdmi monitor

Tags: 16.04, hdmi, external-monitor

I have ubuntu dual-booted with windows on a HP Envy (AMD FX 7th Gen APU), and windows recognizes my external monitor connected via hdmi while ubuntu does not.

I have tried reinstalling amdgpu-pro drivers, which did not work.

Here is output from `xrandr --listmonitors`:

```
Monitors: 1
 0: +*eDP 1920/344x1080/194+0+0  eDP
```

I assume this is just my built-in display

Help!

Comment: What command did you use `xrandr` alone will just tell you info about all the displays connected. What errors (if any) did this "command" produce?

Comment: I've edited the question to show what I used xrandr for... basically I see that it does not recogniz my external monitor.

Comment: what is the output of just `xrandr`?